# Base type is missing for @protocol

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

Short edition:

**Does a `@protocol` with a missing basetype have an inferred basetype of  `NSObject` in Objective-C?**

---

Long edition:

I am binding an Objective C library to C#. One of the protocols in this libraray is missing a base type... Usually I would expect something like this:

```
@protocol Account <NSObject, NSCopying, NSSecureCoding>
```

which I define as:

```
[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface Account : INSCopying, INSSecureCoding
```

But now I am faced with the following:

```
@protocol Configuring
```

so it would be defined as:

```
[Protocol, Model]
interface Configuring
```

But that doesn't make much sense... As per Microsoft's documentation:

> The API definition file consists of a number of interfaces. The
>   interfaces in the API definition will be turned into a class
>   declaration and they must be decorated with the [BaseType] attribute
>   to specify the base class for the class.

So what do I do in this scenario, am I safe to assume the base type of `NSObject` for this protocol?

Comment: Don't confuse class `NSObject` and protocol `NSObject`. `Account <NSObject>` says `Account` conforms to the `NSObject` protocol. Protocols in Objective-C don't have a base type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check [BaseTypeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference#basetypeattribute).

Every `interface` (include `Protocol`) in your definition that has the `[BaseType]` attribute that declares the base type for the generated object.

Refer to [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=vsmac#normalize-the-api-definitions).

Here `InfColorPickerControllerDelegate` is protocol, we should add `[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]` .